# Ipad device orientation problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am presenting MFMailComposeViewController(mailController) using presentModalViewController on my UIViewController, In mailController(subclass of MFMailComposeViewController) class i have overhide shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation as

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

But in my UIViewController class i have overhide  shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation as(this is my project need)

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
    {
return NO;
    }
```

After presenting my mailcontroller, if i rotate the device it works perfectly as expected( supporting landscapeleft/right orientation) in iPhone... But the same code is not working in iPad. Am i doing any mistake here? is it is Apple bug?

I am presenting using this api
     `[myViewController presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES`];

and i am getting this warning on both iPhone and iPad The view controller `<UINavigationController: 0x7720920> returned NO from -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation.`

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

What you're actually saying is "I don't support ANY orientation", which is of course... not true.

You should return true for at least one orientation. For example:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Once the mailcontroller is presented and if i rotate the device the mailcontroller is not rotating in iPad. but i have used the same code for iPhone it is working correctly in iPhone. I think it is apple bug.

Comment: If it's a bug, it's on the iPhone, not the iPad. In any case, this method should not return FALSE for every orientation.

Answer (score 0):

This Method will allow both landscape orientation's:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setSubject:self.title];
[picker setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];
[picker shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[picker shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[picker shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[picker shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown];
[self  presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

This should fix that...

Comment: How and why would it work? You're not "setting" an orientation, this is just calling the "shouldAutorotate" methods over and over and I don't see what that achieves.

Comment: Sorry but a downvote or flag doesn't answer the question. I still don't see why/how would this work. If I'm being an idiot with this and this actually works, please do tell me so.